# {Java} File exists but still showing FileNotFoundException Error

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I need to read a .txt file of integers into a 2d array but when I try to read in the file I get a runetime error saying that the specified file cannot be found. This is the first time I've tried to read in a file so I just need direction on how to do it but I couldn't find an answer this basic.

I have the file of integers named "num1.txt" saved in the same folder as as my java file, so I'm wondering if I don't understand how eclipse and java decide where the file is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i=0;
    j=0;
    int connect4Array[][] = new int[6][7];



    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("num1.txt"));

    while(readFile.hasNextInt())
    {
        for(i=0;i<connect4Array.length;i++)
        {
        connect4Array[i++][j]=readFile.nextInt();
            for(j=0;j<connect4Array[j].length;j++)
            {
            connect4Array[i][j++]=readFile.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide absolute path of that file.

Comment: A compile error or a runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is NOT a compilation error.  It is a runtime error.  You need to learn the difference ... and to say the right thing, or else people won't understand what you are talking about.

---

> I have the file of integers named "num1.txt" saved in the same folder as as my java file.

The problem is that you are trying to access the file in the running application's current directory ... but the current directory is not the place that you think / hope it is.

So where is the application's current directory?  It depends on how you ran the application!

- If you run the java app from a shell, then the current directory will default to the shell's current directory.

  You can change it by `cd`-ing before you run `java ...` and I think you can also specify it using `-Duser.dir=<pathname>`.
- If you run the java app from Eclipse, then the current directory will default to the project directory.  That is probably different to the directory containing the source code.

  You can specify a different current directory in the Eclipse settings for your application's launcher.

---

Alternatively, use an absolute path for the file, or put it into your application's JAR file and read it as a "resource".

Comment: I run java from eclipse and use a flashdrive as my workspace. The workspace is E:/JavaStuff and I have the "num1.txt" saved in the project folder in JavaStuff. Is this the incorrect place to put it?

Comment: In Eclipse, open *Run* - *Run configurations* and select your run configuration. Then click the tab "Arguments". At the bottom, you'll see what the "working directory" is. All relative paths used in the app lauched by this run configuration are relative to that directory. Just as is you executed the java command, in a shell, from this directory.

Answer (score 0):

move the file to where the src folder located.

because the default is project directory in your workspace.

you can use getProperty to check current directory.

String CurrentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 System.out.println("Current working directory : " + CurrentDir);